# findOneAndUpdate not updating

Tags: typescript, express, mongoose

I am trying to update one of my documents stored in mongoose server by using `findOneAndUpdate`. I set it as a PUT request and this is how I defined it.

```
public updateConfigWithType(req: Request, res: Response) {
    configs.findOneAndUpdate({'companyInfo.uniquecompanyid': req.params.id}, { $set: { companyName: "ITSWORKING" }} ,(err,doc) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }else {
          res.json({
              message: 'Succesfully updated this item'
          });
        }
    })
}
```

My PUT request URL is setup like this: `http://localhost:3000/parserConfig/123123wfdwedfwfwefwef`

This is a little piece of the the JSON data that exits in my documents in my mongoose server:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5bbf27ad4cf8a6be65ea6257"
    },
    "companyInfo": {
        "companyName": "example",
        "hashKey": "sdfsdf",
        "hashFunction": "sdfsdf",
        "uniquecompanyid": "123123wfdwedfwfwefwef"
    },
    "version": "1",
    "__v": 0,
    "parserConfig": {
        "id": {
            "fieldName": "key",
            "path": "key"
    },
```

So, I want to be able to find the right document by the uniquecompnayid that is in the URL and I specifically want to UPDATE the `parserConfig` field with what exists in `req.body`. I hardcoded everything for now for testing purposes.. Sending a PUT request currently gives me this answer in Postman:

```
{"message":"Succesfully updated this item"}
```

But nothing has been updated. What am I missing?

**Update**

I changed the code for testing purposes... This is what i tried:

```
public updateConfigWithType(req: Request, res: Response) {
  var query = {'companyInfo.uniquecompanyid':req.params.id};
  configs.findOneAndUpdate(query, {$set:{'companyInfo.uniquecompanyid':"heheheheh"}}, {new:true}, function(err, doc){
      if (err) {
        return res.send(err);
      }
      return res.send(doc);
  });
}
```

The response in postman is the OLD document. Nothing has been changed

**UPDATE after spyros request**

```
10:26:34 PM web.1 |  Mongoose: configs.findOne({ 'companyInfo.uniquecompanyid': '123123wfdwedfwfwefwef' }, { new: true, projection: {} })
10:26:34 PM web.1 |  PUT /parserConfig/123123wfdwedfwfwefwef 200 158.118 ms - 2089
```

**UPDATE new information notice**

I came across this: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7011

where it says:

I noticed that when calling findOneAndUpdate with an update doc property that isn't in the schema, the debug output shows the (wrong)? collection method.

Why would it work to update the same property through Studio 3t but not through my code?

Comment: Some things that come to mind: Did you verify that req.params.id is correctly parsed? Did you verify that the object was not properly updated in the DB? Did you try the update() function instead of findOneAndUpdate? Did you try manually updating the document in mongo directly with findOneAndUpdate, without mongoose, e.g. in the CLI or roboMongo? Also, can you post your schema ?

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful thoughts. It helped me to some extent. Here is the news(going through your questions step by step): 1) will come to this soon 2) Yes 3) No 4) Just tried it using Studio 3T. Running findOneAndOnly did update the companyName. This made me try to use the exact same query in my code(everything is hardcoded even the uniquecompanyID) but it still does not update.(this removes your first question thoughts i guess). debugger still showing that i am doing a findOne. Our schema is like this `const configs = mongoose.model('configs', new mongoose.Schema());`

Comment: Check update please @BenSower

Comment: Ok, but are the fields actually defined in the Schema or do you just use a Mixed Type for your whole definition?

Comment: Ok, just saw your Update! This could actually relate to the mongoose problem, which is also why studio 3T worked properly. So can you try to manually define your Schema with the wanted fields?

Comment: Will give it a try, thank you so much for the updates. Will come back after trying

Comment: @BenSower ok so after talking with my team it seems like defining a schema will be hards since it can be very dynamic. Meaning different for different companies. Is there no other solution for these kinds of problems where defining a schema is not possible? We talked about trying do first do findOne and after finding the document making an update() on that document. So break it up into two operations? What is your thoughts

Comment: Yes, unless you have to update A LOT of documents at the same time, you can also always fetch the single documents, update them manually and then .save() them, which is the best use case for an ORM like mongoose anyways. Alternatively you can always findOne + update, too. Also, as a small note: I don't know your requirements or situation, but having a Schema that is that undefined will probably cause a lot of problems in the (near) future, both maintenance as well as performancewise.

Comment: @BenSower Its just one document per request. But i tried fetching a single document, then using the doc to update it. Did not work. It gives me an error saying `TypeError: Cannot set property 'companyName' of undefined.` Seems like the same error? Could you give a code example of what would work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185646/discussion-between-bensower-and-timo-cengiz).

Answer (score 2):

Enable debug-logging:
`mongoose.set('debug', true);`. This will show you the queries that are executed. I think the error may be related in some misspelling of some attribute or different object-id.
If that doesn't help, update your question with information of the debug-result so i can update my answer.

Comment: I feel it is weird that it says i am using `configs.findOne` when i clearly use `configs.findOneAndUpdate` ??

Comment: yeah, just tested it and it should say `configs.findAndModify`

Answer (score 2):

As of Mongoose v7.6.2, the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) states that:

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

Same as you, I am unable to define a schema for the collection since my documents vary a lot. What did the trick for me is adding `strict: false` to the schema of the collection.

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const DynamicDocumentSchema = new Schema(
  { bar: String },
  { strict: false }
);
```

#### POSTSCRIPT

In case anybody's wondering, you can also add `strict: false` to the update query just like below. This overrides whatever the value of `strict` is in the schema.

```
await DynamicDocumentModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  docId,
  {
    $set: <whatever_update>
  },
  { strict: false }
);
```

Comment: { strict: false } helped me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into similar problem with findOneAndUpdate. After going through a truckload of write-ups and videos, what I found out was that Mongoose's schema constructor supports a second options argument.

One of the these options is "strict", which is meant enforced values passed to mongodb through the model instance is the same as what is specified in the schema.

If the option is set with the value pair { strict: true }, the update will fail if there is any difference between the schema and the values passed in. To override this behavior, strict should be set to false.

As an aside, none of the stuff I read made mention of this options. And I couldn't figure out what was going on until I read the documentation here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/schema-options.html